# Drag and Drop Layout in android 2.2

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, gesture

Is it possible to add a layout in a gestureOverlay view and Drag Drop it in a desired position in android. I am able to add a layout but not able to drag and drop it..I want to know is it possible to do this in version 2.2?

Comment: Are you performing drag & drop on gridview or listview?

Comment: No... its just on a GestureOverlayView ...

Comment: Make sure the parent of the layout is Relative layout and not the Linear layout.

Answer (score 4):

thanks for the help... myself found a solution for this problem... i couldn't implement a drag on this layout, But i adjust in such a way that the layout will come into the position where i touch on the screen...  thanks....

```
private void RunAnimations(MotionEvent event) {

        lastX = event.getX();
        lastY = event.getY();
        Animation b = new TranslateAnimation(Animation.ABSOLUTE,lastX,Animation.ABSOLUTE,event.getX(),Animation.ABSOLUTE,lastY-57,Animation.ABSOLUTE,event.getY()-57);             
        rl.startAnimation(b);  
        b.setFillAfter(true);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this library: [android-dragarea](https://github.com/doffm/android-dragarea)

Answer (score 1):

We implemented a simulare behavior but we derived from ViewGroup and made most of the code by ourself. We also had to use [android.support.v4.view](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/package-summary.html) to make it work for 2.2